# Java - Force Close Program (with running threads)

Tags: java, multithreading, shutdown, java-threads

**In General**
I want to be able to close my Java application even if there are (non-daemon) threads still running. Is it possible in Java? (Coming from C++ world, that seems like a basic request)

**Reason**
I'm building a framework that load external plugins that implement an interface. before shutting down I call a `close()` function on each plugin expect it to release all it resource and stop all his threads. But since the plugin are build by several teams at my workplace I can't really control them and more than once someone didn't close all his threads leaving the application stuck in the shutdown stage.
I would like to close the program forcefully after I called each plugin `close()` function, If they didn't take care of their resources it's their own problem...

Comment: @MarounMaroun `System.exit(int)` will close the JVM no matter what Threads are running.

Comment: Note that this is equivalent of using `SIGKILL` on those threads. It's a last-ditch effort, and the owners of those components need to be shouted at.

Comment: Tell your teams that unmanaged threads are not allowed - they need to go through some kind of ExecutorService.  This can be centrally managed e.g. when going down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to exit the program try

```
 System.exit(0);
```

and try

```
 finalize();
```

if you want to release the resoureces

Answer (score 3):

I think instead of letting all the plugins create threads all over the place, its better to create a [thread pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) in your main program and give the plugins the possibility to submit Runnables and Callables to it. This will give you control over the concurrent tasks in your plugins, i.e. if there are 100 plugins, there dont have to be 100 threads.

Once you restart your program you can call shutdown on the pool, giving the plugins tasks time to tidy up resources. You can define a timeout also.

Comment: (+1) Thanks, we actually start using this approach a few days ago. but I can't prevent the plugins from keep creating their own threads...

Comment: With a byte manipulation library you can!  E.g. aspect oriented programming allow you to target a "new Thread()" which you then can change into throwing a runtime exception.  You probably need to do this in agreement with all the teams.